Biblatex makes substitutions for \textgamma that cause errors
The following example produces an error:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{Author2015,
    author  = "Imogene Mirabell Anne Author",
    title   = "Making {\textgamma}-Iron from Lead",
    journal = "Alchemist",
    volume  = 10,
    number  = 3,
    pages   = "121--134",
    year    = 2038
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

Now run LaTeX, then Biber, then LaTeX again and you'll get an error:
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character ɣ (U+0263)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.

In the .bbl file, the sequence \textgamma has been replaced with the actual character (gamma), which is not declared, hence the error.
Note that replacing \textgamma with \textalpha works fine.
Why does this occur? It seems like a bug in Biber to me.
Additional info: biber version 2.19

According to the Biber developer (see https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/480), this is a feature of Biber documented in section 3.6 of the documentation.
The workaround here (other than the one @DavidCarlisle suggested) is to run biber --output-safechars for such things. It also works to use XeLaTeX instead of PDFLaTeX.

U+0263 is not a Greek gamma. It is Latin gamma. Greek is U+03B3  This seems a strange substitution for biblatex/biber to do but once it's done
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0263}{\textgamma}

would make it work

Thanks for the workaround, but I guess the question is why is biblatex/biber making the substitution in the first place? Is this behavior documented anywhere?

@karlh you'd have to ask on the biber repo or perhaps someone knowledgeable about biblatex/biber will pass by here. it looks wrong to me but I don't know that code well.

I posted this question on the Biber github "issues" list. We'll see what happens from there.

https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/480

The Latin vs. Greek oversight has been corrected in the Biber source, but the issue persists because U+03B3 is not in the Unicode subset pdflatex uses either. I posted the fix as another solution.

@karlh I think you will find the Greek 03xx range is set up if you load the standard Greek packages  see /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/greek-inputenc/lgrenc.dfu
